# SONARQUBE - Validation of project failed, %project is already part of project

Tags: validation, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Getting the below exception during analysis, this is called using sonar gradle plugin and the project has subprojects. Any clues?

I have seen somewhere using branches would help but I do not want to lose my history of analysis so would rather avoid the move.

```
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
  o Module "myjavaclassnamespace.myappname-mymodulename:myprojectname" is already part of project ":"
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Which version os SonarQube are you using ? Can you check that the module "myjavaclassnamespace.myappname-mymodulename:myprojectname" is not already a sub module of another project ?

Comment: Version 5.3, 
I am not aware of any other projects using this module.
Looking at the projects via the server sonar (api/projects?subprojects=true) I see only one entry for my myjavaclassnamespace.myappname-mymodulename:myprojectname module. 
Other details that may be helpful here :
- we recently migrated from Versions 4.4, then 4.5 then 5.3. It is the first time we attempt to analyze this project since the migration.
- we are using the sonarqube gradle plugin

Comment: Hi Julien any clues?

Comment: Is this a new analysis ? Is 'myjavaclassnamespace.myappname-mymodulename:myprojectname module' already belong to the project you're currently analysing or to another project ?

Comment: No it is not a new analysis or new project, as mentioned we recently migrated from Versions 4.4, then 4.5 then 5.3. It is the first time we attempt to analyze this project since the migration but it was analyzed before. myjavaclassnamespace.myappname-mymodulename:myprojectname module is part of one projet only, the one we're analyzing.
What is this error about and how do we get out analysis working ? thanks

Comment: This issue is very strange. Could you please execute the SQL query : "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE kee=':'" ?

Comment: That query returned one row,
name = Unnamed - :
description : 
enabled = 1
scope = PRJ
qualifier : TRK
kee = :
long name : Unnamd - :
created at : 03-21
deprecated_kee = :
Uuid = a key 
all others empty or NULL

Is this unexpected ? Are we expected to rename this row, delete it or possible disable it? thanks

Comment: Following this previous comment, we have tested the following change :
- update the above-mentioned row to enable=0
- re-run our analysis. 
=> Same error. We executed once again the sql command : the row is still there and the value is still 0. Please advise thanks.

Comment: First, you should not update database, or only when everything else has been tried. So please revert, and try to delete this project from the UI : Administration -> Projects -> Management, then search for 'Unnamd' project and delete it. You can also use the WS : POST  "/api/projects/delete? key=:".

Comment: Julien, we have deleted that project via the GUI and this is finally now working (phew..). was this unexpectedly generated during the migration to 5.3 ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great news ! I've no idea what happen. This project was probably already there before, but maybe it was "hidden", and a new behavior from the 5.3 has "revealed" it. I'll post a response to close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sum up the solution discussed in comments :

As described in the error, the problem is coming from the fact than the module key "myjavaclassnamespace.myappname-mymodulename:myprojectname" belongs to the project key ":" (strange name for a key, i have to admit!).

To solve this issue, simply delete the project key ":".